# Calling UserForm_Initialize() in a Module

Tags: excel, vba, module, userform

How can I call `UserForm_Initialize()` in a `Module` instead of the UserForm code object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a module:

```
UserFormName.UserForm_Initialize
```

Just make sure that in your userform, you update the sub like so:

`Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()` so it can be called from outside the form.

Alternately, if the Userform hasn't been loaded:

`UserFormName.Show` will end up calling `UserForm_Initialize` because it loads the form.

Comment: Hi, so where should I put the **UserFormName.UserForm_Initialize**?

Comment: Wherever you like... any vba in the workbook within a Sub or Function.

Comment: Thanks for the method Daniel. Can I put Me to let it Initialize itself? e.g I got a lot of UserForm(s) and I do not want to code each of them.

Comment: you can use a `for each uf in UserForms`  loop?

Comment: In the function, I tried to declare the UserFormName As UserForm/String and then called the name of the form in the parameter but still no luck with that :(

Comment: @all Because Larry's suggestion didn't work, I researched the issue and posted the Q&A here: [How do I load every UserForm without having to call .Show individually?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13965608/1316573)

Comment: I wonder if my request was inappropriate to apply because I barely find any solution yet. I am truly grateful with your effort Daniel. I will keep up with the Q&A mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: I experimented with this solution and ran into problems with the myUserFormName.Userform_Initialize().  As stated @Daniel simply using myUserFormName.Show calls Userform_Initialize(). That is the simpler approach in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the method **UserForm_Initialize should remain private** bacause it is **event handler for Initialize event** of the UserForm.

This event handler is called when **new instance of the UserForm is created**. In this even handler u can initialize the private members of UserForm1 class.

*Example:*

**Standard module code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
  Dim myUserForm As UserForm1

  Set myUserForm = New UserForm1
  myUserForm.Show

End Sub
```

**User form code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_initializationDate As Date

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  m_initializationDate = VBA.DateTime.Date
  MsgBox "Hi from UserForm_Initialize event handler.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, good thought there. What I wanted is e.g. create a function for **UserForm_Initialize** in the **Module** (which I will not specify which UserForm to init YET). Regarding which UserForm to init,  I will later include it in the UserForm. The reason I did this is because I wanted to include the **init** in the **IF ELSE** statement in the Module.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the comment u wrote, sorry. In general u should avoid calling UserForm_Initilize() directry because it will be called by the class UserForm1 itself as a reaction to creation of UserForm1. It is symply an event-handler so it should handle event.

Comment: 1. I have **IF ELSE** statement in **Module1** 
2. Before **END IF**, I want to reset UserForm1  
3. I want the 'reset' function inside the **Module1** 

P.S Sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: It's OK Tan, my english is bad as well :-). Couldn't u just post your code sample?

Comment: I've resolved my problem and posted the solution in my own question above. Do you think it is good?

Comment: And what is UserForms exactly?

Comment: UserForms is where your put the Controls in it and display it as a window. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I VBA-help UserForms is described like this: The UserForms collection is a collection whose elements represent each loaded UserForm in an application.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION
After all this time, I managed to resolve the problem.

In Module:
UserForms(Name).Userform_Initialize

This method works best to dynamically init the current UserForm