# How to reference an Excel UserForm from Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, userform

### CASE:

- I have created an Access database.
- Using Access-VBA I open an Excel workbook to do stuff.
- This workbook (`xlWb`) does complex calculations and also loads an Excel Userform (`UserForm2`) on open.
- So far everything OK. I open `xlWb`, `UserForm2` loads, I do stuff.

### GOAL:

- After this, I need to "refresh" `Userform2`.
- By the term "refresh" I mean either call a custom sub of this UserForm, or unload and reload `UserForm2`.

### QUESTION:

- How can I can reference `UserForm2` from my Access-VBA code?

### WHAT I 'VE TRIED:

By searching I 've only found how to reference a UserForm from
   another workbook.

- The first suggestion was to use `VBA.UserForms` to get a loaded UserForm.

So I 've tried the following references: `VBA.UserForms("UserForm2")`, `VBA.UserForms.Item("UserForm2")`, `VBA.UserForms(0)`, `VBA.UserForms(1)`, all of which threw error: "subscript out of range", which implies that what I 'm writing is not a member of the collection.

- Another suggestion was to create a function that loads and unloads the object.

So I wrote inside an `xlWb`'s module named `Apps` this:

```
Public Sub Refresh_UserForm()
    Unload Userform2
    Userform2.Show
End Sub
```

and in the access sub this:

```
Application.Run "'" & xlWb.Name & "'!Apps.Refresh_UserForm"
```

This throws a

> Run-time error 2517 cannot find the procedure
>   'calc_8.4.xls'!Apps.Refresh_UserForm'

- The same error is also generated when I tried a 3rd similar suggestion to create a function that returns an instance of the object.

Every suggestion is very welcome thank you.

Comment: Don't use underscores in method names! `Application.Run "'" & xlWb.Name & "'!Apps.RefreshUserForm"`will work.

Comment: I 've tried this first but there was no change at all. Thank you though.

Comment: Strange. Now it works for me to with underscore, but it stopped working as I added one to function. Never the less, don't use underscores in methods as at least when you use interfaces, it fails see https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/03/27/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-events/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this works for me:

---

**Note**: for demonstration purposes I created a xlsm file called "Map1.xlsm" with a userform called "UserForm1". Also, you'll need the "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" reference turned on.

---

First, as mentioned above I created an Excel file with the below macro in Module1:

**1).** To open the UserForm for the first time (and refresh):

```
Sub Refresh_UserForm()
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show False
End Sub
```

---

Within Access-VBA I created the following two macros (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32955714/9758194)):

**1).** To open and use the Excel UserForm

```
Option Compare Database
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlWB As Excel.Workbook

Sub mySub()
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\...Path...\Map1.xlsm") 'Specify Path
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.Run "Map1.xlsm!Refresh_UserForm"
End Sub
```

**2).** To Refresh the Excel UserForm

```
Sub Refrsh()
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Run "Map1.xlsm!Refresh_UserForm"
End Sub
```

---

Hopefully this helps

Comment: The mistake was that I used the word "Application" to run the macro, as this refers to the Access application. Finally I replaced it with this: `AppXl.Run "'" & xlWb.Name & "'!Apps.Refresh_UserForm"` where `AppXl` is the object I had already declared to open the Excel application. I 'm marking this as the answer, because that's exactly the point. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

In userform2, add a "Refresh" button and the following procedure:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Refresh_Click()
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

If you have a `UserForm_Initialize` sub and `UserForm_Terminate` sub , you can include the procedures to simulate the unload-reload action.

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Refresh_Click()
    Call UserForm_Terminate
    Call UserForm_Initialize
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

If you need to unload the form and call it back later manually, then you will have to call it back from the actual loaded Excel window (e.g. with a form Button on the worksheet), but cannot be from Access or the xlWb hook.