# Loop Through Userform Controls in Other Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried to loop through the ActiveWorkbook's Userforms via my Personal.xlsb, but can't get the syntax quite right. Here's what I've tried (amongst a zillion other attempts)

```
wbname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

For Each UFm In Workbooks(wbname).Parent.UserForms
    For Each cntrl In UFm

    Next cntrl
Next UFm
```

Thoughts??

Thanks

Dan

Comment: What are you actually trying to do to the controls?

Comment: Hi Rory, I was trying to add the Userforms to a listbox, when clicked, lists all objects in that UF in secondary listbox. I should be able to use the links below to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"Workbooks(wbname).Parent" is the Application object.

The Application does hold a "Userforms" collection - however this is only a collection of userforms which are currently loaded, and does not include all userforms which exist as code modules in your VBA project.

You'd have to access the userforms' code modules via the VBA Editor. Please see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx - Guidance about how to access code modules themselves

[How do I load every UserForm without having to call .Show individually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965608/how-do-i-load-every-userform-without-having-to-call-show-individually) - A related question on this site which may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

to loop through userform controls even in another workbook isn't trivial. A possible solution requires VBE reference to MS Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3.

I didn't find a complete example anywhere, so the following working code might help:

```
Sub ListAllControls()
 Dim vbc As VBIDE.VBComponent           ' Reference to MS VBA Exte 5.3 !!!
 Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
 Dim sMsg, sLit As String
 Dim cnr, vbcnr As Long
 Dim i, imax As Integer
 imax = Workbooks.Count
'------------------
'Loop all Workbooks
'------------------
 For i = 1 To imax
    sLit = Chr(i + 64) & "."
  ' a) build message new workbook
    sMsg = sMsg & vbNewLine & String(25, "=") & vbNewLine & sLit & " WorkBook: " & _
           Workbooks(i).Name & _
           vbNewLine & String(25, "=")
    '-------------------
    'Loop all Components
    '-------------------
    For Each vbc In Workbooks(i).VBProject.VBComponents
      ' Only if Component type is UserForm
        If vbc.Type = vbext_ct_MSForm Then
         ' increment component and ctrl counters
           vbcnr = vbcnr + 1000
           cnr = vbcnr
         ' b) build message new component
           sMsg = sMsg & vbNewLine & String(25, "-") & vbNewLine & sLit & cnr & " '" & _
                  vbc.Name & "'" & vbNewLine & String(25, "-")
         '------------------
         ' Loop all Controls
         '------------------
           For Each ctrl In Workbooks(i).VBProject.VBComponents(vbc.Name).Designer.Controls
             ' increment ctrl counter
               cnr = cnr + 1
             ' c) build messages controls)
               sMsg = sMsg & vbLf & "  " & Format(cnr, "0 000") & " " & _
                      ctrl.Name
           Next
        End If
    Next vbc
  Next i
 Debug.Print sMsg
End Sub
```

Have fun,

Tony