# Python win32com Show VBA UserForm

Tags: python, excel, vba, ms-word, userform

I'm trying to control Word using a Python3 script using win32com. I've imported a VBA UserForm, and am trying to show it but receiving an error. Some code:

```
from win32com.client.dynamic import Dispatch
from win32com.client.dynamic import ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT
import win32com.client as win32

app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')

app.Visible = True        
app.Documents.Open('.../'+current_doc+'.docx')                

try:
    app.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents \
        .Import('.../UserForm1.frm')
    app.Run('UserForm_Initialize()')
```

The script succesfully imports the UserForm, but upon attempting to initialize, it is throwing this error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Forms.Form.1', "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.", 'fm20.hlp', 0, -2147352573), None)
```

Does anyone know a way to initialize the UserForm successfully? I can't use an  alternative to using a VBA UserForm unfortunately, as that part is already written entirely.

Thanks!!!

Note: I've verified the app.Run() command is correct by also separately importing a module to call the UserForm, and running it. Same error. However, if I then open the VBA console and run the same module, it successfully opens the UserForm.

Comment: I'm feeling a bit out of depth here but it seems to me that you are calling an initialize event without qualifying which form you wish to initialise.

Comment: My apologies, I should clarify that while the UserForm_Initialize() sub I'm trying to call is uniquely named, you're right that I'm not using full context when I call it. From some Excel examples, I've tried things like: 
**UserForm1.UserForm.Initialize()**
..without any success.

Comment: I found a comment on another ask stating that the 'can't move focus' error is actually more like an 'out of range' error, so I think you're probably right that I'm not calling the script in the right way.

Comment: Try UserForms(Name).Userform_Initialize.  I found this snippet here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964780/calling-userform-initialize-in-a-module

Comment: That's a good reference. I've updated my question with an answer based on it and some other options I was able to rule out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution now. After importing the UserForm as before, I import an initialization module:

```
Sub init()
    UserForm1.UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
```

After that, I use the app.Run() to call this script, which in turn calls the UserForm:

```
app.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents.Import('.../UserForm1.frm')
app.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents.Import('.../init.bas')
app.Run('init')
```

The important difference to what I was trying before is leaving '()' off the .Run reference to the init() Module. Thanks to Steven Laycock above for the reference and reminder.

As an alternative, I also attempted to call the UserForm directly from the program using the reference above, something like:

```
app.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents.UserForms('UserForm1').UserForm_Initialize
```

but had no luck. Since I have a working solution, I won't be researching the direct call any further.